# Convert dictionary to list collection in C#

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

I have a problem when trying to convert a dictionary to list.

Example if I have a dictionary with template string as key and string as value. Then I wish to convert the dictionary key to list collection as a string.

```
Dictionary<string, string> dicNumber = new Dictionary<string, string>();
List<string> listNumber = new List<string>();

dicNumber.Add("1", "First");
dicNumber.Add("2", "Second");
dicNumber.Add("3", "Third");

// So the code may something look like this
//listNumber = dicNumber.Select(??????);
```

Comment: Are you asking for a list of keys from the dictionary? If so there's a Keys Property on Dictionary that will give you that.

Answer (score 225, accepted):

To convert the Keys to a List of their own:

```
listNumber = dicNumber.Select(kvp => kvp.Key).ToList();
```

Or you can shorten it up and not even bother using select:

```
listNumber = dicNumber.Keys.ToList();
```

Comment: this was really helpful. I needed to apply .Where(...) to the dict before returning the keys, but that method doesn't return a dictionary, so I couldn't access the Keys property. using this select after the where worked great

Comment: The problem with this solution is the order of the values and keys, that will be different due to hashing. You can add to each instruction .OrderBy(T).ToList(); being T the type of the value/key, think about explaining it in your (correct) answer dude

Answer (score 35):

Alternatively:

```
var keys = new List<string>(dicNumber.Keys);
```

Comment: Working with the .NET Compact Framework 2.0 (so no Linq) this was the best option for me.

Comment: If you cannot use LINQ this options seems the best.

Answer (score 21):

If you want to use Linq then you can use the following snippet:

```
var listNumber = dicNumber.Keys.ToList();
```

Answer (score 15):

If you want convert Keys:

```
List<string> listNumber = dicNumber.Keys.ToList();
```

else if you want convert Values:

```
List<string> listNumber = dicNumber.Values.ToList();
```

Comment: This will work, but might not be in the order you expect, even the dict was ordered by keys before, dict.Values is not...

Answer (score 7):

```
foreach (var item in dicNumber)
{
    listnumber.Add(item.Key);
}
```

Comment: Why not in the end :)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to pass the Dictionary keys collection into one method argument.

```
List<string> lstKeys = Dict.Keys;
Methodname(lstKeys);
-------------------
void MethodName(List<String> lstkeys)
{
    `enter code here`
    //Do ur task
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```cs
List<string> keys = dicNumber.Keys.ToList();
List<string> values = keys.Select(i => dicNumber[i]).ToList();
```

This ensures that `dicNumber[keys[index]] == values[index]` for each possible `index`.