# Deserialize JSON String with multiple possible object name in one class

Tags: c#, json, class

I'm doing a server request of 3 different users from a game.

I got this JSON String as a result:

```cs
{
   "d4r1o": {
      "id": 1040806,
      "name": "D4R1O",
      "profileIconId": 596,
      "revisionDate": 1399366400000,
      "summonerLevel": 30
   },
   "snnovox": {
      "id": 65728,
      "name": "SN Novox",
      "profileIconId": 548,
      "revisionDate": 1399369344000,
      "summonerLevel": 30
   },
   "gmbecken": {
      "id": 421545,
      "name": "GM Becken",
      "profileIconId": 26,
      "revisionDate": 1399160360000,
      "summonerLevel": 30
   }
}
```

So in order to deserialize this string I have these classes

```cs
public class RootObject
{
    public SummonerDto d4r1o { get; set; }
    public SummonerDto snnovox { get; set; }
    public SummonerDto gmbecken { get; set; }
}

public class SummonerDto
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int profileIconId { get; set; }
    public long revisionDate { get; set; }
    public int summonerLevel { get; set; }
}
```

This works just fine, but what if the user wants to make a request about his own username, for example: snyucax

```cs
    {"snyucax": {
   "id": 48985,
   "name": "SN YucaX",
   "profileIconId": 504,
   "revisionDate": 1399257043000,
   "summonerLevel": 30
}}
```

Is there a way to make only one object in the **RootObject** Class that let me take any username without having to especify that name as an object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a dictionary for this. If you're using JSON.NET, then the code would look like:

```
var users = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, SummonerDto>>(jsonDataString);
```

Then you could get the user by going:

```
var user = users["d4r1o"];
```

*e: Seems `Tim S` just beat me to the punch, haha.*

Comment: This works perfectly, actually your second line helped me to understand it, but now what can I do to make a List of all my users requested?

Comment: This question has your back covered on turning a Dictionary into a List. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3968543/convert-dictionary-to-list-collection-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your data is better modeled as a dictionary. Use

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, SummonerDto>>(myJson)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not hardwire your objects. Instead use a dictionary or send the username and form a json object based on the user and deserialize it at the client's browser o app